# Run cvb in mahout 0.8

Tags: mahout, lda, topic-modeling

The current Mahout 0.8-SNAPSHOT includes a Collapsed Variational Bayes (cvb) version for Topic Modeling and removed the Latent Dirichlet Analysis (lda) approach, because cvb can be parallelized way better. Unfortunately there is only documentation for [lda](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Latent+Dirichlet+Allocation) on how to run an example and generate meaningful output.

Thus, I want to:

- preprocess some texts correctly
- run the cvb0_local version of cvb
- inspect the results by looking at the top n words in each of the generated topics

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So here are the subsequent Mahout commands I had to call in a linux shell to do it.
$MAHOUT_HOME points to my mahout/bin folder.

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/mahout seqdirectory \
    -i path/to/directory/with/texts \
    -o out/sequenced

$MAHOUT_HOME/mahout seq2sparse -i out/sequenced \
    -o out/sparseVectors \
    --namedVector \
    -wt tf

$MAHOUT_HOME/mahout rowid \
    -i out/sparseVectors/tf-vectors/ \
    -o out/matrix

$MAHOUT_HOME/mahout cvb0_local \
    -i out/matrix/matrix \
    -d out/sparseVectors/dictionary.file-0 \
    -a 0.5 \
    -top 4 -do out/cvb/do_out \
    -to out/cvb/to_out
```

Inspect the output by showing the top 10 words of each topic:

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/mahout vectordump \
    -i out/cvb/to_out \
    --dictionary out/sparseVectors/dictionary.file-0 \
    --dictionaryType sequencefile \
    --vectorSize 10 \
    -sort out/cvb/to_out
```

Comment: Is there any way to retrive eache topics documents? or the other way, to retrive document topics?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to JoKnopp for the detail commands.

If you get:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

you need to add the command line option "maxIterations":
--maxIterations (-m) maxIterations

I use -m 20 and it works

refer to:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1141